# Ember.js: Proper way to cast Em.$.getJSON into a promise and bind response to controller context?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm fetching some data with $.getJSON that I want to asynchronously bind to controller context. I've come up with this in my route - which works, but I'm not happy with it:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  Em.RSVP.Promise.cast(Em.$.getJSON((this.get('ENV.apiBaseURL')) + "/users/current/live_matchday_stats")).then((function(_this) {
  return function(s) {
    return _this.controller.set('matchdayStats', Em.Object.create(s));
  };
}
```

Then, in my template, I can, for example, use:

```
Foo: {{matchdayStats.foo}}
```

And it works just fine. Is there a better way to write this (perhaps without promise casts and Em.Object creation) - I know this automatically works if I put Em.$.getJSON into a model hook.

Comment: The `Em.$.getJSON()` method returns a Promise by default, no need to cast. Since Ember is planning to [move away from controllers](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-2-0-moving-away-from-controllers/6728), you should probably just add this to your Route's `model` hook. Any reason you're not?

Comment: Because my model is something else, and this data is just something unrelated to model, but I still need to load it and show in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [DS.PromiseObject](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html)

```
var matchdayStats = DS.PromiseObject.create({
  promise: Em.$.getJSON((this.get('ENV.apiBaseURL')) + "/users/current/live_matchday_stats")
});

controller.set('matchdayStats', matchdayStats);
```

This is the way Ember Data accesses/displays related objects and the properties of those objects in templates.

Comment: I don't want to use this as a model, because my model is already something else.